# How to add background color to the list view of bottom safe area SwiftUI iOS 14

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14, swiftui-list

I'm trying to add background color to the bottom safe area with list view.
I know how to add background color to the list cell, but it doesn't apply to the safe area. Is there any possible way?

**Note:** I did try `ZStack` and `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea`, I need to use **SwiftUI 2.0 List View**, not `LazyVStack` or `SwiftUI 1.0 (iOS 13) List View`

```
List {
  ForEach(0..<100) { index in
     Text(String(index))
     .listRowBackground(Color.red.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add:

```
UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
```

and put the `List` in a `ZStack`:

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ZStack {
                Color.red.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                List {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 100) { index in
                        Text(String(index))
                            .listRowBackground(Color.red)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively instead of using `ZStack` you can set the color directly:

```
UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(.red)
```

Note that this will set the `backgroundColor` *globally*.